# How to use wrapAsync in Meteor

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, fibers, node-fibers

I am having trouble figuring out how to use wrapAsync properly using Meteor.  I am currently working with node-apac and the Amazon Product Advertising API.

If am trying to run the following code, how do I run it asynchronously:

```
opHelper.execute('ItemSearch', {
    'SearchIndex': 'Books',
    'Keywords': 'harry potter',
    'ResponseGroup': 'ItemAttributes, Offers'
}, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

I have tried to watch several videos, but am having trouble

Comment: wrapAsync is used to make asynchronous calls synchronous by using fibres and waiting for the asynchronous call to return.  So your two questions "how to use wrapAsync" and "how do I run it asynchronously" are at odds with each other.  Consider logging the err as well when calling `opHelper.execute` to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Meteor.wrapAsync` takes an asynchronous method like `opHelper.execute` and makes it synchronous. It can do this so long as the last param taken by the method returns a callback where the first param is the error and second the result. This is just like your method!

You make a new method that is synchronous:

```
var opExecuteSynchronous = Meteor.wrapAsync(opHelper.Execute, opHelper);
```

The first param `opHelper.Execute` is the method you want to make asynchronous, and the second param is the context of the method (`opHelper`).

You can use this synchronously now:

```
var results = opExecuteSynchronous('ItemSearch', {
    'SearchIndex': 'Books',
    'Keywords': 'harry potter',
    'ResponseGroup': 'ItemAttributes, Offers'
})
```

This will throw an error if `err` is called instead of `results` in the callback.

Comment: Hi @Akshat, this doesn't seem to be working for me.  I get an error that says TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: @DavidMckee try again there was a typo in my code, fixed it now